# Validation Caching in Symfony >= 3.1

Tags: symfony

In a Symfony 3.1 application (which developement has been started on Symfony 2.7) I have this config item in `config_prod.yml`:

```
framework:
  validation:
    cache: validator.mapping.cache.doctrine.apc
```

To use this setup with PHP7 I needed to change this to:

```
framework:
  validation:
    cache: validator.mapping.cache.doctrine.apcu
```

Since Symfony 3.1 there is as well a new Cache component which for the system is configured like:

```
framework:
  cache:
    system: ???
```

and the [official blog article](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-1-cache-component) states for it:

*"cache.system is where Symfony components store their contents (e.g. the Serializer and **Validator metadata**) (...) If your server has APCu installed, the cache.system pool uses it. Otherwise, it falls back to the filesystem cache."*

What I'd like to understand is whether the framework->validation->cache definition is still required or if that's part of the cache.system pool.

In later case - if I understand it correctly - framework->validation->cache could be removed and still an enabled APCu would cache validation annotations.

**EDIT**

If my assumption is correct then validations would be cached by the new Symfony ApcuAdapter and not by the Doctrine APC/U Cache anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [upgrade documentation](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.1/UPGRADE-3.1.md):
"The framework.serializer.cache option and the service serializer.mapping.cache.apc have been deprecated. APCu should now be automatically used when available."

So this means indeed the old configuration can be deleted without any replacement as long as apcu is installed and enabled.

Comment: The question was about `framework.validation.cache` and your answer about `framework.serializer.cache` ?